convert nginx server config to apache
Please help me convert nginx server config to apache
server {
    listen       8088;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   "../webs";
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ /RPC2|RPC2_Login|RPC_Loadfile/ {
        proxy_pass http://$http_self_targetip;
        break;
    }   
    
    location ^~ /web_caps/ {
        proxy_pass http://$http_self_targetip;
        break;
    }
}

I can't convert it at all
This not work
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/RPC2|RPC2_Login|RPC_Loadfile/.*
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/RPC2|RPC2_Login|RPC_Loadfile/$1 [NC,R=302,L]
